# How to stop Android Studio from crashing while indexing at start-up?

Tags: android-studio

There was an update to Android Studio this morning, and since then I have been unable to open any of my projects, either as myself or as an admin.
It seemed to crash mostly at the point of indexing Android API 29, but repeated runs shows that it stops at various other indexing moments (I was trying to record the messages. but they flash by too quickly).
Is there some file that might tell me what is causing the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Went into "Task Manager," found a lot of "dart.exe" processes running, ended them all, then started Android Studio again.
Worked this time.